# div with is influencing font size on iPhone

Tags: html, text, size, width

On my page http://www.somersetsights.co.za/en/index.html I have 4 div's (div.service) width text in it. The first three div's have a width of 256px. Div number 4 has width of 900px (inline style width:auto).

When I display my page on my iMac and my iPad all 4 div's have the same text size and text style. On my iPhone the text of div number 4 has a different text size and style as the first three div's.

When I define the width of div number 4 also with 256px the text size and style is the same as in the other three div's. As soon as the width is back to 900px text size and style is changing. As I said this happens only on my iPhone. Not on my iPad and my iMac.

What do I have to do to avoid text size and style change when I increase div width?

Answer (score 0):

I can't simulate the situation with Chrome Dev Tools, but when I try to access your website from the iPhone Simulator I can actually see the problem.

But I guess that's because of CSS; in `style.css`, at row 18, you declare `font-size: 100%;`, and this declaration is propagated to the text in your `div.service`.

Probably when you override the width of the `div`, the size of the font is computed accordingly to it. The difference in behavior could be due to a bug in Safari or simply because of the different properties of iOS screen (scale factor, orientation, virtual size of desktop, ...).

Try replacing `font-size: 100%;` with another size, for example `12px` or in `em` maybe. Then the font size shouldn't be influenced by div's width anymore.